# Funciones de grupo MIN y COUNT

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy estudiando justo estas funciones y al intentar incluirlas en una subconsulta no obtengo el resultado esperado, no se si las estoy usando bien, os dejo enunciado y luego dos variantes en las que estoy trabajando:

Visualizaremos nombre del departamento, el nº de empleados que tiene, suma de los ingresos y
descuentos de todos sus empleados del departamento o departamentos con menor número de
empleados.

```
SELECT D.NOMBRE, COUNT(T.CODDEP) AS NRO_EMPLEADOS, SUM(J.INGRESO) AS TOTAL_INGRESOS, SUM(J.DESCUENTO) AS TOTAL_DESCUENTO
    FROM N_JUST_NOMINAS J INNER JOIN N_TRABAJAN T
            ON J.CODEMP = T.CODEMP
        INNER JOIN N_DEPARTAMENTOS D
            ON T.CODDEP = D.CODDEP
    GROUP BY D.NOMBRE
        HAVING D.NOMBRE IN (SELECT COUNT(*), D.NOMBRE
                            FROM N_TRABAJAN T, N_DEPARTAMENTOS D
                            WHERE T.CODDEP = D.CODDEP
                            GROUP BY D.NOMBRE);


SELECT D.NOMBRE, COUNT(T.CODDEP) AS NRO_EMPLEADOS, SUM(J.INGRESO) AS TOTAL_INGRESOS, SUM(J.DESCUENTO) AS TOTAL_DESCUENTO
    FROM N_JUST_NOMINAS J INNER JOIN N_TRABAJAN T
            ON J.CODEMP = T.CODEMP
        INNER JOIN N_DEPARTAMENTOS D
            ON T.CODDEP = D.CODDEP
    GROUP BY D.NOMBRE
        HAVING COUNT(T.CODDEP) IN (SELECT MIN(COUNT(*))
                                FROM N_TRABAJAN
                                GROUP BY CODEMP);
```

Comment: Dame el DD de las tablas involucradas y podria darte una sugerencia.

Answer (score 1):

Tu error puede estar en el numero de empleado, ya que en "COUNT(T.CODDEP)" te retorna el numero de filas, lo que yo haria es solamente dejar el nombre del campo que tienes asignado para el numero de empleado y te lo deberia devolver correctamente